# MySQLi & mysql_real_escape_string() Errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using OOP MySQLi to connect to my database. I have checked my credentials and everything is good to go.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
       printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
       exit; 
    }

    if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id=' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']))) { 
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
            printf("%s (%s)\n", $row['name'], $row['place_id']); 
        } 
        $result->close(); 
    } 

    $mysqli->close();
```

This code is generating a error:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access
denied for user '-removed-'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
/var/www/vhosts/communr.com/httpdocs/pbd/places.php on line 396

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to
the server could not be established in
/var/www/vhosts/communr.com/httpdocs/pbd/places.php on line 396
```

I can't figure out why I am getting these errors. They started showing when I moved servers recently. I am establishing an SQL connection before the query.

Do you all think some setting could be messed up on my new server?

Thanks!

Comment: What is strange to me is that if I do `'SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id="' . mysql_real_escape_string(1354) . '"'` I get errors, if I do `'SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id="1354"'` I get the expected result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` requires a connection to be established via `mysql_connect` in order to work.  `$mysqli->real_escape_string` requires a `mysqli` object to work.  So,

Use [`MySQli::real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead:

```
'SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id='.$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

But note that you'd need to quote it in order to be safe:

```
'SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id=\''.$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).'\'';
```

However, since it looks like an integer, you should cast it as such instead of escaping it:

```
'SELECT * FROM places WHERE place_id='.(int) $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: It's better to quote it because if $_GET['id'] is empty, the query will fail.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you ircmaxwell & Capsule, you are right too. It is strange it was working fine on my old server.

Comment: @Capsule: casting to an int will always generate an int.  If `$_GET['id']` is empty, it'll return `0`.  So it's better to not quote it as then the DB would need to do type mangling rather than PHP...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I usually filter values before casting random things to what I really need, just to avoid querying the DB for nothing. Anyway, it would be interesting to bench which one is faster at casting, PHP or MySQL ;-)

Comment: @ircmaxell, btw why do we need to use a connection to mysql simply to clean some input? Why not simply use an *offline* function to clean the input?

Comment: @Pacerier: Simple. Because how you escape is context dependent upon the settings that you currently use for the mysql connection. Depending upon the preferences and settings that you set, it will escape the string differently. For example, let's say you set the charset to `ISO-8859-1`, it will escape `0xbf27` as `0xbf5c27`, but if you set the charset to `GBK`, it will escape it as `0x5cbf5c27`. Because one will create an invalid char stream, and the other will not. Check [this out](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)...

Comment: `MySQli::real_escape_string`: Non-static method `mysqli::real_escape_string()` cannot be called statically ...