# From php a Mysql connection error when using parameters in phpdao2.6

Tags: php, mysql, php-dao

I've been using [phpdao2.6](http://phpdao.com/) on a local Mac MAMP installation and another remote red hat linux server fine. I've recently moved to an EC2 amazon ubuntu flavour and installed a LAMP set up.

Suddenly I've found I'm getting mysql connection errors, but not always:

```
[09-Jul-2013 21:09:11 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/html/mycobber/class/sql/SqlQuery.class.php on line 40

[09-Jul-2013 21:09:11 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/html/mycobber/class/sql/SqlQuery.class.php on line 40
```

I only get these errors on functions in the MyObjectMySqlExtDAO.class.php if I'm using the

```
$sql .= 'and ca.enabled = ? ';

.....

$sqlQuery = new SqlQuery($sql);

$sqlQuery -> set('Y');
```

style syntax. If I change this syntax to ..

```
$sql .= " and ca.enabled = 'Y' ";
```

It works fine. I'm at a loss to understand why this is happening and I don't want to use the second method as the input is not sanitized.

I suspect the issue is a php setting of some kind.

On the EC2 instance I'm using:

```
php: 5.3.26
apache: Apache/2.2.24 (Amazon)
```

My local MAMP setup is

```
php: 5.4.10
apache: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
```

Any ideas out there?

Comment: this error says your password is wrong Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: A link to the server could not be established this error confirm this something went wrong like hostname, username, password

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQLi & mysql\_real\_escape\_string() Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080953/mysqli-mysql-real-escape-string-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to include the connection as the second parameter to the mysql_real_escape_string function. Looks like on the EC2 ubuntu instance it didn't like it without this.

```
mysql_real_escape_string($string, $resource)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

So that escaping can take the current connection character set into account, [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) needs an active connection to the database.  According to linked manual page:

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. **If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments.** If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Emphasis added.

In this DAO library, the connection is opened by invoking `ConnectionFactory::getConnection()`.  You'll need to ensure that there's an active connection *before* performing placeholder substitution.

Please be aware that the code quality of this library leaves something to be desired.  It's also hard-coded to use the *deprecated* `mysql_` family of functions.  You probably should not rely on this library being usable in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Hi Charles, yes I'd noticed this but was making use of the 'build php objects from tables' component during a quick dev phase, I'm going to swap out the library later on. thanks for the input.